# Can't use apply function in a column having some 'nan' values

Tags: pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

This is a Machine Learning problem, in `Python 3.0` environment. I have been working
with a Wines dataset for a classification problem. I want to use LabelEncoder() on the value of the feature 'country' present in the dataset. Since there are some
'nan' values in 'country', I am trying to encode those values only which are not
null. However, the code that I wrote:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
le = LabelEncoder()

dataset = pd.read_csv('winemag-data-130k-v2.csv')

a = pd.Series(data = le.fit_transform(dataset[dataset.loc[:, 'country'].notnull()].loc[:,'country']))
dataset[dataset.loc[:, 'country'].notnull()].loc[:, 'country'].apply(lambda i: i, a)
```

This however always generates an error as follow:

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

**Update** : I know this is little hacky solution, but I think it works

```
dataset.loc[:, 'country'] =dataset.loc[:, 'country'].replace(le.classes_, le.transform(le.classes_))
```

**Old Answer**
If I am correct in assuming that you wish to encode your countries using the `LabelEncoder()`, then the syntax of the last line is incorrect, since you are trying to map a Series incorrectly using the lambda expression. It should be

```
dataset.loc[:, 'country'] = a[dataset.loc[:, 'country'].notnull()]
```

[image]

Comment: Nope. It is not working. In 'a', I have stored the encoded values of those values 
in 'country' which are not null. And in the next step I wish to replace those non-null values with their corresponding encoded value in 'a'.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the complete code ? Also which python, sklearn and pandas version are you using ?

Comment: I am using Python 3.6, Anaconda Installation. I only wish to replace the non-null entries in 'country' column with their respective encoded data that I have stored in 'a'.